# Percentage calculator outputting integer only

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a working percentage calculator (As demonstrated below). The 1st Input is for the inital number, the 2nd input is for the percentage and the 3rd outputs the answer.

I am trying to get the answer displayed in the 3rd input field as an integer (whole number only). What JS is needed to achieve this and to show the value in the input field?

```
 <input type="number" class="input" id="without-visitors">
 <input type="number" class="input" id="without-conversion">
 <input type="number" class="input" id="without-formfillenquiries" readonly>



<script>
        $('#without-visitors, #without-conversion').change(function() {
          var withoutvisitors = parseFloat($('#without-visitors').val())
          var withoutconversion = parseFloat($('#without-conversion').val())
          var withoutformfillenquiries = parseFloat($('#without-formfillenquiries').val())
    
          $('#without-formfillenquiries').val(withoutvisitors * withoutconversion / 100);
    
    
          });
      </script>
```

Comment: I tried out your code in a jsfiddle, it seems to work - it's placing only an integer in the third input. https://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=bP5r0weMNu

Comment: May you use a stack snippet in your example so we can run it too?

Comment: If I add the numbers 111 & 11 to the first 2 fields it outputs 12.21

I need this to be a whole number as it represents people.

Comment: My mistake. Changing the ending bit to `.val(Math.round(withoutvisitors * withoutconversion / 100))` will round to the nearest whole number.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=5ojQ75UrBf - inputting 111 and 11 gives just 12.

Comment: Amazing Stuff, Tzvi2, Thank you for your help! This has resolved the issue :)

Comment: @Tzvi2 May either one of you answer the question with a runnable example? Both jsfiddle links are broken for me.

Comment: @evolutionxbox sure, see below.

Answer (score 0):

I added the Math.round() function to the last line - $('#without-formfillenquiries').val(withoutvisitors * withoutconversion / 100); in order to round the result to the nearest whole integer.

```js
$('#without-visitors, #without-conversion').change(function() {
          var withoutvisitors = parseFloat($('#without-visitors').val())
          var withoutconversion = parseFloat($('#without-conversion').val())
          var withoutformfillenquiries = parseFloat($('#without-formfillenquiries').val())
    
          $('#without-formfillenquiries').val(Math.round(withoutvisitors * withoutconversion / 100));
    
    
          });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" class="input" id="without-visitors">
 <input type="number" class="input" id="without-conversion">
 <input type="number" class="input" id="without-formfillenquiries" readonly>
```

Comment: I know it's already mentioned in the comments above, but may you add what you did that solved the issue?

Comment: @evolutionxbox it's in this answers code. I added the `Math.round()` function to the last line - `$('#without-formfillenquiries').val(withoutvisitors * withoutconversion / 100);` in order to round the result to the nearest whole integer.